# how take this imageurl out using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

i use htmlunit for access website in java.how ever i did everything .the problem arise while accessing to dom element which has `no id no name` . so i serch and found i need to use xpath for access that element .this is the structure of it..

```
 <tbody>
 <tr>
    <td class="contenttxt01" colspan="2">
      <b>
        Student Login
      </b>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text" align="left" valign="top" width="60%">
      Register Number/Student Id 
    </td>
    <td width="40%" align="left">
      <input class="Dropdownbox" name="txtRegNumber" id="txtRegNumber" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text" align="left" valign="top" width="60%">
      Password 
    </td>
    <td width="40%" align="left">
      <input class="Dropdownbox" name="txtPwd" id="txtPwd" maxlength="20" size="20" tabindex="0" type="password"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text" align="left" valign="top" width="60%">
      Verification Code 
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="left">
      <input name="txtverifycode" id="txtverifycode" maxlength="6" size="8" class="listboxtext" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" type="verifycode"/>
      <img src="/srmswi/Captcha"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="txtSN" id="txtSN"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txtPD" id="txtPD"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txtPA" id="txtPA"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

in this case i want to get image src .

```
<img src="/srmswi/Captcha"/>
```

can some one tell me how to get it using xpath

```
page.getByXPath("//image[i can't get it]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will query for the `img` element having `src` attribute equal to `/srmswi/Captcha`:

```
page.getByXPath("//img[@src='/srmswi/Captcha']");
```